# How can I play "The Sims" without an optical drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive, games

I'm trying to play “The Sims 3” on my MacBook Retina which doesn't have an optical drive.

From what I understand, my options are:

- Buy/Borrow an external optical drive
- Use the Bonjour service on a PC (never used it)
- Copy the CD to my PC as an ISO/IMG file of some kind?

What is the best way to allow my new Mac to play the Sims 3 without the power drain and physical weight of an external CD ROM?

Answer (score 2):

Like most PC/Mac games sold now, The Sims 3 is available for purchase as a digital download. It looks like you can [buy it from the official site](http://store2.origin.com/store/ea/en_US/custom/pbPage.FP_Sims3_en_NA#all) (note the distinct *download* and *physical* options).

Once you purchase it, you’ll be able to download it and install without any physical disks.

It also seems to be available for sale on the [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?snr=1_4_4__12&term=sims) online store, also as a download, and as of July 15, 2013, it’s 50% off.